# handle out of memory exception in android

Tags: android, out-of-memory

In android I calculated the heap memory and dumped it into the file and now how to clear the data so the heap size will decrease and application runs normally.

```
  public static void logHeap() {
            Double allocated = new Double(Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize())/new Double((1048576));
            Double available = new Double(Debug.getNativeHeapSize())/1048576.0;
            Double free = new Double(Debug.getNativeHeapFreeSize())/1048576.0;
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
            df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
            df.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

        Log.d("tag", "debug. =================================");
        Log.d("tag", "debug.heap native: allocated " + df.format(allocated) + "MB of " + df.format(available) + "MB (" + df.format(free) + "MB free)");
        Log.d("tag", "debug.memory: allocated: " + df.format(new Double(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()/1048576)) + "MB of " + df.format(new Double(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/1048576))+ "MB (" + df.format(new Double(Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()/1048576)) +"MB free)");
    }
```

Comment: its the job of the garbage collector to free memory.

Comment: but its not clearing automatically. my applicaitons is running very slowly

Comment: you need to code such that you don't run into memory leaks

Comment: its showing 15mb after the process also when i naviagte to th next screen

Comment: your activity will be paused not destroyed. so it will occupy some space. do you get out of memory exceptions?

Comment: have a look at this http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en//events/io/2011/static/notesfiles/MemoryManagement.pdf

Comment: (http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/) this is the url how i had handled the images

Comment: i had followed the above url format only.. but after loading more number(50+) images then if i move to the next screen the heap size is not clearing.. if I move continously  i will get forceclose in some activity and the total memory is cleared at that position.So now i want to know what is happening whileforce close is called

Comment: an any one help what is to be called